# Error while building vlc-unity with Docker-Compose on Win 10

Tags: docker-compose, libvlcsharp, vlc-unity

My Machine:
WIN 10 PRO x64 (DUal XEOn with 40 cores, 64G RAM)

Installed 64 bit versions of **GitHub desktop** and **Docker Compose**.

Successfully checked out https://github.com/videolan/vlc-unity.git
in a Windows ADMIN command Prompt, after CD-ing into the local directory with vlc-unity repo when I try to run:
docker-compose -f .gitlab-ci.yml up

I get the following error:  **ERROR**: In file '..gitlab-ci.yml', services 'stages' must be a mapping not an array.

I have verified that the indentation is correct in gitlab-ci.yml file, any other suggestions ?

After comments below did the following (EDIT: 16 Sep 2020):

I installed **Ubuntu 20 on a VM Ware Workstation for Win**.
checked out VLC repo under "BuildingVLC/vlc",

cd into "/BuildingVLC/vlc/extras/ci" and then ran

"**gitlab-runner exec docker uwp64-libvlc-llvm**"

throws an error:
**Runtime platform arch=amd64 os=linux pid=11242 revision=fd488787 version=13.4.0-rc1
FATAL: open .gitlab-ci.yml: no such file or directory**

What am I still missing ?

Comment: I'm confused as to whether this command is correct? ```docker-compose -f .gitlab-ci.yml up```

Comment: Never used `docker-compose -f .gitlab-ci.yml up` so I don't know, but you should always build on Linux.

Comment: Thank you folks for replying. Can you suggest how should I built it on Linux VM, a link to tutorial should suffice. thanks

Comment: "gitlab-runner exec docker uwp64-libvlc-llvm"

throws an error: Runtime platform arch=amd64 os=linux pid=11242 revision=fd488787 version=13.4.0-rc1 FATAL: open .gitlab-ci.yml: no such file or directory